# How to use DocumentsProvider.moveDocument with TreeUri?

Tags: android, kotlin, uri, documentfile

I want to move a DocumentFile from one Location to another. The Uris are aquired via ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENTTREE and stored.

However, when i try:

```
val resolver = context.contentResolver
val srcUri = Uri.parse(myUriFromACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
val srcDocument = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, srcUri)
val targetUri = anotherUriFromACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

DocumentsContract.moveDocument(resolver, srcUri, srcDocument.uri, targetUri )
```

I get an error:

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3Anew%20test%20folder%2FTdf%2FmayBeDeleted%2Fexterner
```

I have not found a way to convert the TreeUri to a normal one. Is this the problem? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Btw. the Uri in the error message is my srcUri; but i guess the target Uri wont be accepted either.

Comment: Your target uri is an existing folder. Like your source uri. I think the target folder should be non existing.

Comment: moveDocument takes three uris as parameter. You did not explain what they should be and how you used those parameters.

Comment: ok, all three uris are similar constructed: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:%3Anew%20test%20folder%2 pointing to my source folder, content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:%3Anew%20test%20folder%20myFile.acc my file at this location and content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary:%3Aother%20folder my target; can I somehow move my file with these parameters?

Comment: Please remove that comment as it is unreadable. Put all info in your post please.